# MongoDb Driver 2.0 C# Filter and Aggregate

Tags: c#, mongodb, filtering, grouping, facet

I'm playing around with the new driver of mongodb 2.0, and looking for adding some facetted searchs (Temporary move ,before using elastic search).

Here is some method where I created to build the agreggation. I guess that it should work.

As parameter I passed also a filterdefinition in the method. 
But I don't find how to limit my agreggation to the filter.

Any Idea ???

```
    private void UpdateFacets(SearchResponse response, FilterDefinition<MediaItem> filter, ObjectId dataTableId)
    {

        response.FacetGroups =new List<SearchFacetGroup>();

        SearchFacetGroup group = new SearchFacetGroup()
        {
            Code = "CAMERAMODEL",
            Display = "Camera model",
            IsOptional = false
        };

        using (IDataAccessor da = NodeManager.Instance.GetDataAccessor(dataTableId))
        {
            var collection = da.GetCollection<MediaItem>();
            var list = collection.Aggregate()
                .Group(x => ((ImageMetaData) x.MetaData).Exif.CameraModel, g => new { Model = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                .ToListAsync().Result;


            foreach (var l in list)
            {
               group.Facets.Add(new SearchFacetContainer()
               {
                   Code = l.Model,
                   Display = l.Model,
                   Hits = l.Count, 
                   IsSelected = false
               });
            }
        }

        response.FacetGroups.Add(group);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't used facet, but with Mongo driver Aggregate has .Match operation that accepts a filterdefinition.

```
collection1.Aggregate().Match(filter)
```

Comment: It looks good :=) I tried to put the Match after the group :)